# How to check XMLHttpPRequest 's unique ID?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to complete my website request [Tamper tool](https://github.com/ttodua/Tamper-Request-Javascript-Tool) written in JavaScript, However, I am facing my last issue. Below is example function to hook to `XMLHttpRequest` request. Each request immediately starts with `readyState`=1, however, only after server returns response, it gets `readyState`=4.

https://jsfiddle.net/v4mgna51/

However, my problem is that, once in every 1 second, the request is fired, and before it gets response from server, another request might have started in the meanwhile, so making me unable to track (inside readyState==4 ) to check to which initiated call does this "response" corresponds to.

How can I find that out?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I saw was a bit ugly approach ([adding uniqueID manually](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/uniquely-identifying-ajax-requests-responses)), like this:

```
    this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(event) { 
        if(this.readyState == 1){
            event.target.uniqueID = Math.floor( (Math.random() * 99999999) + 1 );
        }
        if(this.readyState == 4){
            console.log(event.target.uniqueID);
        }
    }, false);
```